# Rearranging Table after PDF extraction with Tabula

Tags: python, pandas, loops, pdf, tabula

I have used Tabula to extract a table from a PDF. It worked will minus a little clean up. The last issue I have and I'm not sure how to overcome is that if a cell row is too large (i.e. it contains wrapped text) then Tabula splits it into two rows with the row containing almost all the information and the second row containing the second half of the text of the first cell in the row above but 'None' in the rest of the cells.

Here is an example:

```
    df

       House_Type             Area        Shape

       Blue House       3456          circle
       Red house        2345          square
       Small Green      987           square
       House            None          None
```

Ideally I'd be able to add the text in column "House_Type" row "house" to the row above in column "House_Type" and then get rid of the row "house" with 'none' in it.

The end result looking something like this:

```
      df

       House_Type             Area        Shape

       Blue House             3456          circle
       Red house              2345          square
       Small Green House      987           square
```

I thought doing it as a loop might work

```
    def row_funct( df):
        row = 0
        for row in df:
            if area = None:
            row += 1
```

But I'm stumped on where to go from here or if this is even the right direction

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue and wrote the following function (modified slightly to match your example):

```
def CleanRunResults(df):
    for row in range(len(df)-1, -1, -1):
        NoArea = pd.isnull(df['Area'].iloc[row])
        NoShape = pd.isnull(df['Shape'].iloc[row])
        YesType = pd.notnull(df['House_Type'].iloc[row])
        PrevRow = row - 1
        if NoArea and NoShape and YesType:
            df['House_Type'].iloc[PrevRow] = '{0}{1}'.format(df['House_Type'].iloc[PrevRow],df['House_Type'].iloc[row] )
    df.dropna(subset=['Shape', 'Area'], how='all', inplace=True)
    df = df[['House_Type', 'Shape', 'Area']]
    return(df)
```